# Approximation of trig functions

Tags: trigonometry, approximation

I need help to understand how following terms can be approximated:

$\cos(a \sin\omega_mt)≈1$

$\sin(a \sin\omega_mt)≈a \sin\omega_mt$

if $0 < a < 0.4$

Comment: You mean, how to justify the approximation? Start by looking at $\cos{x}$ and $\sin{x}$ and their Taylor expansions. Then you can truncate terms and voilà ...

Comment: @Matti P. Thank you!